# How to get displacement working on a completed house?

Tags: texturing

I made a house with blender but how can I apply displacement modifiers only to the walls and not to the whole object?

Answer (score 0):

You can create vertex groups in edit mode and attach them to the displacement modifier.

1. Select your wall's vertices.
2. Press space and search for add vertex group
3. Assign the vertex group to the modifier.